# invalid column name in HAVING

Tags: sql, sql-server

Anyone have an idea why the 'CoID' value isnt recognized?

```
select 
    ac.AccountID
    , max(case when c.Name = 'email' then c.Data end) as Email
    , max(case when c.Name = 'phone' then c.Data end) as Phone
    , max(a.CompanyID) as CoID
from paul_AccountContacts ac
left join paul_Contact c on c.ID = ac.ContactID 
left join paul_Account a on a.ID = ac.AccountID
having (CoID in (1506))                  --ERROR HERE
order by ac.AccountID
```

Error:

> Invalid column name 'CoID'.

Comment: Having is used to filter groups, Where is used to filter rows. Seem you just to change this to "Where CoID = 1506". No need to use IN for a single value.

Comment: or use "having max(coid) = 1506".

Comment: @SMor Why do you put `max()` in the `HAVING` statement again?

Comment: @SeanLange unfortunately that gave me the same error

Comment: Haha yeah because CoID is an alias. Change it to CompanyID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, you want to filter the single record then use `where` clause instead of `having`

```
select 
      ac.AccountID,
      max(case when c.Name = 'email' then c.Data end) as Email,
      max(case when c.Name = 'phone' then c.Data end) as Phone,
      max(a.CompanyID) as CoID
from paul_AccountContacts ac
left join paul_Contact c on c.ID = ac.ContactID 
left join paul_Account a on a.ID = ac.AccountID
group by ac.AccountID
where a.CompanyID  = 1506 -- use IN clause whenever you have multiple CompanyID ids
order by ac.AccountID
```

However, `having` is used when you want to filter out after some *aggregation* or filter out based on *aggregation* or withing the *aggregation*

So. your query will look like with `having` clause :

```
select 
      ac.AccountID,
      max(case when c.Name = 'email' then c.Data end) as Email,
      max(case when c.Name = 'phone' then c.Data end) as Phone,
      max(a.CompanyID) as CoID
from paul_AccountContacts ac
left join paul_Contact c on c.ID = ac.ContactID 
left join paul_Account a on a.ID = ac.AccountID
group by ac.AccountID
having max(a.CompanyID) = 1506
order by ac.AccountID;
```

Comment: the second part with the having clause worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In logical query processing `SELECT` is executed after `HAVING` or `WHERE` clause clause. therefore it is not able to recognize column name created in `SELECT`. Try using `max(a.CompanyID)` instead:

```
    select 
        ac.AccountID
        , max(case when c.Name = 'email' then c.Data end) as Email
        , max(case when c.Name = 'phone' then c.Data end) as Phone
        , max(a.CompanyID) as CoID
    from paul_AccountContacts ac
    left join paul_Contact c on c.ID = ac.ContactID 
    left join paul_Account a on a.ID = ac.AccountID
    Group by ac.AccountID
    having max(a.CompanyID)  = 1506                  --ERROR HERE
    order by ac.AccountID
```

Comment: I get `An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
`

Comment: @Rilcon42 Can you try executing above query again and let me know if it works?

Comment: I get: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'.`

Comment: My bad @Rilcon42. `Group by` should be executed before `HAVING`.

Comment: Your code works perfectly as well, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help! @Rilcon42

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the group by clause, which you obviously want since you are using aggregation functions. I assume from your select what you want is:

```
group by ac.AccountID
```

Afterwards, are you trying to take only CompanyIDs of 1506, or you want to only show grouping results for which max is 1506: The first is done like this:

```
Where a.CompanyID  = 1506
```

the second like this

```
having max(a.CompanyID)=1506
```